# Тире или дефис?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

1. На границе детей пересаживают в автобусы фирмы-резидента другого государства.
2. Идею учреждения нового праздника подхватили многие агентства-партнеры США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и т.д.

До сих пор не совсем ясно правило относительно таких ситуаций. Буду благодарна, если дадите на него ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Идею учреждения нового праздника
> подхватили многие агентства-партнеры
> США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и
> т.д.

Нужен ДЕФИС: *агентства-партнеры.* НЕ ТИРЕ! Приложение -- ОДНОСЛОВНОЕ!

Распространённым это приложение было бы в том случае, если бы эти агентства действительно являлись **ПАРТНЁРАМИ** США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и т.д.

На самом деле они только РАСПОЛОЖЕНЫ в США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и т.д.

А ПАРТНЁРАМИ эти агентства являются для АГЕНТСТВА -- автора идеи праздника, о котором идёт речь!

А речь -- об этом:

> Примечательно, что практически
> накануне **Дня святого Валентина** —
> 12 февраля — отмечается этот
> профессиональный праздник —
> Международный день брачных агенств...
>
> Идею учреждения нового праздника,
> принадлежащую одному из украинских
> брачных агенств, подхватили многие
> агентства-партнеры США, Канады,
> Германии, Франции, Италии, Испании и
> Швейцарии.
>
> Источник: Новости Facenews -
> http://www.facenews.ua/birthdays/2013/104494/

**P.S.**

Правила -- здесь: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66

и здесь (§ 154): http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

Comment: Тогда надо писать так: "Идею учреждения нового праздника подхватили многие агентства-партнеры в США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и т.д.

Comment: А лучше вообще убрать слово "партнёры": "Идею учреждения нового праздника подхватили многие агентства (в) США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии..."

Answer (score 2):

В обоих случаях ставится тире, так как к существительному относится не одиночное, а распространенное приложение: фирма, которая является резидентом другого государства; агентства, которые являются партнерами США, Италии, Испании и Швейцарии и т.д.

У Лопатина (обособление приложений): Одно (а не два)тире ставится, если приложение имеет более конкретное значение в сравнении со значением определяемого слова: Источник силы от матери — родной земли представляется для всех источником важным и целебным (второе тире опущено).